# "Upper bound on" vs. "upper bound of"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrase-usage

I have seen both usages, and want to learn how to choose the appropriate option.

Comment: Could you provide the context that you want to use it in?

Comment: @Nicole My bad. I had mostly algorithms analysis and design in mind, but dang's answer seems to identify a pretty general pattern.
So for my field, an example would be an upper bound ON the running time of an algorithm, which (the running time) could have an upper bound OF O(n).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usage I have most often seen in quantitative technical fields is that there is an upper bound *on* a variable. And if you use "an upper bound *of*..." you are referring to that limit, rather than the variable that is being limited.

For example, "there is an upper bound *of* 50 miles per hour *on* my car's velocity."

See [Mathwords.com](http://www.mathwords.com/u/upper_bound.htm) for "upper bound *of*" and [this article ("A Simple Upper Bound on the Redundancy of Huffman Codes"](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1013158)) for many, many examples of "upper bound *on*" usage.

Comment: Followed the sound advice of @EdwinAshworth. Thanks!